# What can I change to get k-means to cluster my data the way it's expected to in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working on an assignment that requires us to perform 20-dimension K-Means clustering on a data-set ([data-set is here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00445/)) and to test it's purity by comparing the clusters to classification bins. I have tried for days to find a combination of clusters and bin ranges that show meaningful clustering but I have had no luck. From what I can tell, all of the clusters are appearing in all of the ranges at one point or another.

I've used python and the pandas and sklearn libraries to try to accomplish this. As per our assignment, the last column representing the "absenteeism in hours" is to be left out of the clustering and then binned for comparison afterwards. I've created the list of clusteres using the KMeans method and appended them to a new dataframe containing only the ID, number of hours absent, cluster and the binned absent hours ranges. When I look at this table, I'm seeing very little observable clustering happening, as all of the clusters occur in all the ranges. Here is the first several rows of my table (sorted by clusters):

```
      ID  Absenteeism time in hours  Cluster Absentee hours bins
 0    11  4                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 415  13  4                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 414  18  4                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 413  20  3                          0        (2.0, 3.0]        
 412  3   4                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 411  24  2                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 410  20  8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 409  11  8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 408  3   8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 416  33  4                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 407  36  0                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 405  1   0                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 404  36  8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 403  36  3                          0        (2.0, 3.0]        
 402  36  2                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 401  1   8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 400  13  0                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 399  10  8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]        
 398  3   16                         0        (15.0, 120.0]     
 406  24  0                          0        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 397  23  8                          0        (3.0, 9.0]
```

And later on in the table:

```
 242  14  2                          4        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 552  28  2                          4        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 244  18  8                          4        (3.0, 9.0]        
 296  34  3                          4        (2.0, 3.0]        
 297  13  8                          4        (3.0, 9.0]        
 298  3   1                          4        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 299  22  64                         4        (15.0, 120.0]     
 300  5   0                          4        (-0.1, 2.0]       
 301  11  16                         4        (15.0, 120.0]
```

As far as I can see the clusters do not seem to be clustering as expected. As I said earlier, I've been at this for days and I've done hours of research, reading documentation, watching youtube videos, reading dozens of tutorials and I just can't seem to figure out what, if anything, I'm doing wrong. I've tried clusters from k=3 to k=6 with various bins of various sizes. My instructor seems to be quite sure that we should be finding effective clustering using this data-set. I'm not sure if there's just something I'm missing. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
np.set_printoptions(threshold = sys.maxsize)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', -1)



# import dataset as pandas dataframe
absences = pd.read_excel('Absenteeism_at_work.xls')

#set columns to be used for k-means (exclide absentee hours)
xRange = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
x = absences.iloc[:, xRange].values

bins = [-0.1, 2, 3, 9, 15, absences['Absenteeism time in hours'].max()]
absences['Absentee hours bins'] = pd.cut(absences['Absenteeism time in hours'], bins)


#perform clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
kmeans.fit(x)
labels = kmeans.labels_
#print(labels)

#add labels column to original dataframe
absences['Cluster'] = labels

#print relevant columns
columns = ['ID', 'Absenteeism time in hours', 'Cluster', 'Absentee hours bins']
sorted_by_cluster = absences[columns].sort_values(['Cluster'])
print(sorted_by_cluster)
```

Any input you all could provide would be very much appreciated. My understanding is that I should definitely be seeing some sort of correlation between the bins and clusters. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You might want to calculate the [homogeneity score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html) to assess if your clustering really is performing poorly.

Comment: Thanks, great resource. I tried this, and got a 1.0, but I don't believe I did it right. I understand that labels_pred should be kmeans.labels_ but what should I be entering for labels_true? A list of my bins?

Comment: Never include ID columns...

Comment: I am required to use all columns except the last one. The instructor specifically stated we should be doing a 20 dimensional cluster analysis.

Comment: Then you should educate your instructor. A lear-squares optimization on IDs is *nonsense*.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your data appropriately!

Do not include ID columns.

Do not use coded columns (don't compute differences of ICD codes).

Why would you include day of the week etc.?

Think about what function the algorithm tries to optimize - does that make any sense on your data?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as I replied in your comment above, I'm explicitly required to include all columns except for the last one.

Comment: That is a stupid assignment then, if that *really* is what is expected, and not a misinterpretation on your side.

Comment: It is really what was expected, and was not a misinterpretation on my side. Considering I confirmed this to be true with her a number of times, and that she specializes in data mining, I think it's probably not that big of a deal within the goal and scope of the assignment.